# Oraclize external rest api call failure handling

Tags: solidity, contract-development, oracles, error

Using https://oraclize.it, I can perform something like this

```
oraclize_query("URL","json(https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes).status",
              '{"postcodes" : ["OX49 5NU", "M32 0JG", "NE30 1DP"]}');
```

but now, when the oraclize offchain bot access the url, what if

- dns resolution of api.postcodes.io fails?
- the answer doesn’t contains the expected json `status` field?
- the expected answer is received, but with an http status code of 404? or 403?
- the Oraclize request asks for 2 differrent json fields of the same request but only 1 of the 2 is found by the parser (is neither fields provided in the `__callback()` or only one)?

In each case, is the Oraclize call to `__callback` on the contract cancelled? or sent with garbage? or empty?

Comment: Why the downvote?